# Iterate through column, find match, and copy content of cells in the same row

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a code that iterates through a specific column (spreadsheet   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pebqQFpwkC5OQ59wBEG9RXggHkt1pYhbm3cFBw8rLWE/edit?usp=sharing) and sends a message for each match it finds in the column (the match is the word “Complete”).
But what I need is to find the match AND include the content of some cells that are in the same row in the message.
Any ideas of how to do it?
Thanks.

```
function completeInfoToExtend() {
var ss = 
SpreadsheetApp.openById("1pebqQFpwkC5OQ59wBEG9RXggHkt1pYhbm3cFBw8rLWE");
var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Controle de Status');
var lastRow = sh.getLastRow();
var data = sh.getRange(1,50,lastRow,1).getValues();
for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {

if (data[i][0] === "Complete") {

MailApp.sendEmail({
 name: "XXXX",
 to: "email@email.com",
 subject: "Action needed - Send codes to Master Data team",
 htmlBody: message1

  }); 
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function completeInfoToExtend() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById("1pebqQFpwkC5OQ59wBEG9RXggHkt1pYhbm3cFBw8rLWE");
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Controle de Status');
  var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
    if (data[i][49] === "Complete") {
      var message1=Utilities.formatString('column1: %s, column2: %s, column3:%s',data[i][0],data[i][1],data[i][2]);
      MailApp.sendEmail({name: "XXXX",to: "email@email.com",subject: "Action needed - Send codes to Master Data team", htmlBody: message1}); 
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to grab more data in your getRange() request. It's hard to tell you specifically what to do without knowing which column the data you want to include is in, but this will grab the data in the adjoining cell (to the right) and include that in the email body.

```
function completeInfoToExtend() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(
    "1pebqQFpwkC5OQ59wBEG9RXggHkt1pYhbm3cFBw8rLWE"
  );
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Controle de Status");
  var lastRow = sh.getLastRow();
  var data = sh.getRange(1, 50, lastRow, 2).getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][0] === "Complete") {
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        name: "XXXX",
        to: "email@email.com",
        subject: "Action needed - Send codes to Master Data team",
        htmlBody: "<h1>This is the data:<h1><p>" + data[i][1] + "</p>"
      });
    }
  }
}
```